# Query mongoose based on today date

Tags: mongoose

How do I query MongoDB based on today's date? I have tried using Momentjs is not working. Here is the code and many thanks in advance and greatly appreciate any helps.

```
//mongoDB data
appointmentdate:2021-05-28T03:00:00.000+00:00
appointmentdate:2021-05-26T15:00:00.194+00:00
appointmentdate:2021-05-26T15:30:00.481+00:00
    
//Nodejs
const appointment = await Appointment.find({appointmentdate:{$eq: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')}}).sort({appointmentdate: 1})
```

Comment: Are you trying to find all appointments on that day, as in, from midnight to midnight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When querying a date object, it needs to be compared to other dates, not a string (which is the output of the `.format('...')` method).
To find all items on a day, you will need to query a range of dates, which can be done with the [`$lt` and `$gte` operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/lte/).

`$lt` means "less than", and `$gte` means "greater than or equal to". It's best to have one side of your range use an "or equal to" to avoid items exactly on the start/end of your range (in this case midnight) being missed by queries.

Define the start and end of your range, then query for items within it. Make sure to convert moment objects to native JS Date type so Mongoose can understand them.

```
const start = moment().startOf('day').toDate()
const end = moment().startOf('day').add(1, 'day).toDate()

const appointment = await Appointment.find({
  appointmentdate: {
    $gte: start,
    $lt: end
}}).sort({appointmentdate: 1})
```

Comment: Thanks caffeinated.tech